# Show NMAImage as UIImage

Tags: here-api

I want to show a maneuver icon provided in the HereMaps SDK that is of NMAImage type and show that in a UIImage placeholder, swapping out the image each time the maneuver icon changes. The instruction is a little vague in their documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAImage.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAImage(im)UIImageRepresentation

Under UIImageRepresentation ("Provides a UIImage representation of the NMAImage"  - which is exactly what I'm looking for) it says only:

`func uiImage() -> UIImage?`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The UI Image representation of an NMAImage can be retrieved by calling the uiImage() method of an NMAImage object.
Example:

```
let maneuverIcon = NMAImage(<Image source>)
// Now you can get the UI image representation of maneuverIcon as:
let uiIcon = maneuverIcon?.uiImage()
```

Note that, `uiIcon` will be nil if `maneuverIcon` could not be converted.